# IPython priority order of _repr_ methods using display

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

In IPython (and therefore Jupyter notebooks), I can define methods such as `_repr_html_` and `_repr_svg_` on an object, and these will be used when calling `IPython.display.display(my_obj)`. But if multiple such methods are defined and possible to use (e.g. viewing a notebook in a web browser, and displaying an object which has both `_repr_html_` and `_repr_svg_` methods), which  one will take priority? In the documentation notes at https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display there is the following list, but it doesn't state that this is in priority order

- HTML
- JSON
- PNG
- JPEG
- SVG
- LaTeX

Is there documentation somewhere on this that I have missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The priority is decided by the frontend, not IPython. IPython sends them all (unless you use display with `exclude` or `include` keywords. Reason being that once the notebook is saved you might want to open with another frontend with a different display priority order.

Classic notebook has the following order (outputarea.js line 1080):

```
OutputArea.display_order = [
    MIME_JAVASCRIPT,
    MIME_HTML,
    MIME_MARKDOWN,
    MIME_LATEX,
    MIME_SVG,
    MIME_PNG,
    MIME_JPEG,
    MIME_GIF,
    MIME_PDF,
    MIME_TEXT
];
```

For JupyterLab this is a bit more complicated, each registered mimetype can get a rank assigned to it (and likely changed), As extension can install mime-handler this will depends on the extensions you have.

Nbconvert also have it's own order for html-like exporters:

```
display_data_priority = List(['text/html', 'application/pdf', 'text/latex', 'image/svg+xml', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'text/markdown', 'text/plain']
```

and for tex-like exporter:

```
'display_data_priority' : ['text/latex', 'application/pdf', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/svg+xml', 'text/markdown', 'text/plain']
```

I wrote a demo for [JupyterCon 2017 – Jupyter: Kernels, Protocols, and the IPython Reference Implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GExKsQ-OU78) (around t=25min) to show that notebooks could have a dropdown to switch which representation(s) is shown on a per-cell basis which stills need to be actually implemented and merged in the main branch if you have the usage/motivation to contribute.

Comment: This is really useful, thanks @matt. We have an issue that, for some objects, the SVG representation may be so large as to stall or crash the browser. But from what you are saying, if I call `display()` on such an object, even if the _repr_html_ method is the default frontend display, it will also send the SVG representation, and hence risk stalling.

Comment: In that case you can do display(object=..., exclude={'svg'}) I believe and it will not compute and not send the SVG.